# A few glitches with this python chat program

Tags: python, python-3.3

I have three machines connected to  a hub without internet and I am trying to use a code that talks like a chat service in python 3.3. However when I run the send code it stagnates at Listening for connection... and when I start the second program on the other machine to receive it comes up with the following error message:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python33\recv.py", line 5, in 
s.connect((host,port))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.

Here is the first code to send the message:

```
host = "127.0.0.1"
port = 4446
from socket import ^
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print("listening for connections...")
q,addr = s.accept()
data = input("Data to be sent: ")
q.send(data)
s.close()
```

Here is the second code to receive:

```
host = "86.10.137.206"
port = 4446
from socket import *
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((host,port))
msg = s.recv(1024)
print("This is the message:",msg)
s.close()
```

What can be done to resolve this problem. Is it to do with the 127.0.0.1

Comment: Host means different things in each program. In the first program, you bind the socket to the host IP. In the second one, you try and connect to the "host" IP. Is `host` in the second program the IP of the first program?

Comment: Sorry I do not understand what you mean. Are you suggesting that the 127.0.0.1 is correct for the host but the receive function should be running with the physical laptops IP?

Comment: Yes, "127.0.0.1" means "this computer's IP". The second program needs to run with the computer the first program is running on's IP.

Comment: Hi I just tried that and I got the same issue's as listed in my initial question. What would be your next stage

Comment: Check that you can connect. Try pinging the IP address from the second computer.

Answer (score 0):

The IP address 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address, and is treated special.  It is used for interprocess communication on the local system -- packets do not get off the system.

Please lookup and list the ip addresses of each system.  You should have a router or something assigning IP addresses though DHCP or something.  Use ifconfig to show all interfaces, and obtain the ip address for the interface plugged into your hub.

Each client must be configured to listen to the server address.

Change your host port to = '', as that is pythonese for INADDR_ANY.  By specifying 127.0.0.1, you are specifying listen on the loopback port,

```
host = ''
port = 4446
from socket import ^
s = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind((host,port))
s.listen(1)
print("listening for connections...")
q,addr = s.accept()
data = input("Data to be sent: ")
q.send(data)
s.close()
```

Comment: I am trying to communicate on the local system and not on the external system. I understand that 127.0.0.1 is the loopback address. Would I just need to change the UP for the second piece of code

Comment: The server needs to listen on an external interface.  The client needs to connect to the server external interface.  Humor me, on your server, put the its ip address into the host, and on the client, put same address.

Comment: Here is a page explaining what happens when you specify various addresses to bind to, INADDR_ANY vs. specific address, http://www.scottklement.com/rpg/socktut/bindapi.html

Comment: also, check your firewall settings.